# Itext7 convert html to pdf (asp.net core 2.1) get error "Cannot access a closed stream"

Tags: asp.net-core, itext7

I installed iText7.pdfhtml and use class iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter to convert html string to pdf. Once I try to access the output pdf stream, I got error "Cannot access a closed stream". I need to read the memory stream in order to upload to Azure blob storage.

My Code is as below:

```
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlString, stream);

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:StorageConnectionString"]);

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("receipts");

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf");

await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

stream.Dispose();
blobUrl = blockBlob?.Uri.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf` closes the stream that was passed to it after the conversion process is over. However, because you are using a `MemoryStream`, you can still access its content even after it was closed.

If you want to use the contents as a stream again, you can create a new one and use it afterwards:

```
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(pdfStream);
pdfStream.Dispose();
```